# How do I setup suiteapp report 360 in my NetSuite environment

Tags: netsuite

I just got the report 360 suiteapp for NetSuite and was wondering about the steps to install it in the sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make sure that you have got a confirmed licence provisioned for the NetSuite Enviornment you want to install the SuiteApp in, then:

1. Log in to NetSuite as Administrator
2. Navigate to Customization -> SuiteBundler -> Search & Install Bundles
3. Enter “106006” in the KEYWORDS field and click on Search
   (this is the bundle id for Alterview Report 360)
4. Click on “Alterview Report 360”  (the Name field)
5. Click on the “Install” button and answer “OK” in the popup window to proceed.
6. Click on "Install bundle"-button
7. Answer "OK" to the question "Are you sure?" to start the installation

If you also want some of the pre-built reports to use as inspiration just to the same steps but for bundle ID 120140

After the installation assign the “Report 360 Editor Admin” role to your selected users (be aware that this is an Admin role and has full access to many standard records and features).
Using Report 360 Editor Admin role, navigate to Report 360 -> Setup -> Update Subscription and click on “Check Subscription” button to make sure your license is activated.